# What are the maximum number of stars any one general can have?

Tags: dragons-of-atlantis

In the interest of building the strongest armys and generals, I would like to focus one general at a time to get his stars.  What is the maximum number of stars any one general can have, and do they lose stars if they are benched while I level another general up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of stars a general can have is 5.

They will not lose any stars if they are benched while you level up other generals.